# What do we know about the author of "The Patristic Gospels: An English Version of the Holy Gospels as They Existed in the Second Century"?

Tags: textual-criticism, biblical-scholarship

The author's name given in the book is as follows: Roslyn D'Onston.  I saw a footnote in reference to this book while doing some reading so I looked it up.  I was happy to find that the work was public domain where I live so I got a digital copy free of charge.  I was also happy to read the following on Google: "This work has been selected by scholars as being culturally important, and is part of the knowledge base of civilization as we know it."

All seemed fine and well up to this point and I enjoyed reading through the translation of the Gospels and accompanying notes.  As I often do, I decided to Google the author to learn more.  That's where things got extremely weird.

Apparently, this fella was involved in the occult and was suspected in the murders related to Jack the Ripper.  As in...he was suspected to BE Jack the Ripper!  You just can't make this stuff up, I guess.

Anyway, due to the Jack the Ripper connection, I can't find much of anything about the author and his education/theology.  He seems to understand Greek reasonably well and even mentions prominent scholars of the time by name (like Bishop Westcott).  I'm just wondering if anyone here knows more about his background and credibility.

Wikipedia's article on [Robert Donston Stephenson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Donston_Stephenson) and *The Guardian*'s article ["New Ripper suspect's ritual killings obeyed occult decree"](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2002/jul/28/humanities.books) links him to D'Onston.

I'm not very well informed on news sources and their credibility so maybe these are way off base.

The Guardian article claims that D'Onston published the Patristic Gospels and then was never seen or heard from again.

Comment: More sourcing is required to evidentially connect the author of the 'Patristic Gospels', variously cited as [Roslyn D'onston](https://www.forgottenbooks.com/en/books/ThePatristicGospels_10243803) or [Roslyn Da Onston](https://blackwells.co.uk/bookshop/product/The-Patristic-Gospels-by-Roslyn-D-TmOnston-author/9781104320096) to the journalist known as [Robert Donston Stephenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Donston_Stephenson). But it would be interesting to know why he claimed that his version was accurate to the 2nd Century. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Please provide links to the references you have made in your question. Otherwise you are requiring would-be answerers to repeat your research, unnecessarily.

Comment: _This work has been selected by scholars as being culturally important, and is part of the knowledge base of civilization as we know it. This work was reproduced from the original artifact, and remains as true to the original work as possible. Therefore, you will see the original copyright references, library stamps (as most of these works have been housed in our most important libraries around the world), and other notations in the work._ [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VB8ZjgEACAAJ&source=gbs_book_other_versions).

Comment: This work is the collation of quotations made by the early Church Fathers (of the 2nd Century) such that the author has presented the four gospel accounts (not from original manuscripts, but) from only the quotations made in other literature.

Comment: Thank you, Nigel.  Appreciated.  I've added a couple of links.